# gym retro reward for moving forward

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

How can I reward an agent to move forward in a game like super Mario bros? The only data I have is the score and lives but is there a way to get the coordinates of an agent? I'm using NEAT to train my agent here is the code. I am currently rewarding it to get the highest score possible and rewarding it for pressing the Right button won't work because it will just push into a wall and farm rewards until the timer runs out.

```
import retro
import numpy as np
import cv2
import neat
import pickle

env = retro.make('SuperMarioWorld-Snes', 'Start.state')

imgarray = []

xpos_end = 0


def eval_genomes(genomes, config):
    for genome_id, genome in genomes:
        ob = env.reset()
        ac = env.action_space.sample()

        inx, iny, inc = env.observation_space.shape

        inx = int(inx / 8)
        iny = int(iny / 8)

        net = neat.nn.recurrent.RecurrentNetwork.create(genome, config)

        current_max_fitness = 0
        fitness_current = 0
        frame = 0
        counter = 0
        xpos = 0
        xpos_max = 0

        done = False
        # cv2.namedWindow("main", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

        while not done:

            env.render()
            frame += 1
            # scaledimg = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # scaledimg = cv2.resize(scaledimg, (iny, inx))
            ob = cv2.resize(ob, (inx, iny))
            ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ob = np.reshape(ob, (inx, iny))
            # cv2.imshow('main', scaledimg)
            # cv2.waitKey(1)

            imgarray = np.ndarray.flatten(ob)

            nnOutput = net.activate(imgarray)
            for i in  range(len(nnOutput)):
                nnOutput[i] = int(nnOutput[i])
                if nnOutput[i] < 0:
                    nnOutput[i] = 0


            ob, rew, done, info = env.step(nnOutput)

            # xpos = info['x']
            # xpos_end = info['screen_x_end']

            # if xpos > xpos_max:
            # fitness_current += 1
            # xpos_max = xpos

            # if xpos == xpos_end and xpos > 500:
            # fitness_current += 100000
            # done = True




            fitness_current += rew
            print(env.statename)
            if fitness_current > current_max_fitness:
                current_max_fitness = fitness_current
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter += 1

            if done or counter == 250:
                done = True
                print(genome_id, fitness_current)

            genome.fitness = fitness_current


config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                     neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                     'config.txt')

p = neat.Population(config)

p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
p.add_reporter(stats)
p.add_reporter(neat.Checkpointer(10))

winner = p.run(eval_genomes)

with open('winner.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(winner, output, 1)
```

Comment: I don't know if it can gives position but you could try to use `cv2` to compare current frame with previous frame - if it doesn't move then many pixels are the same on both frames - and then you can count the same pixels. If number of the same pixel is bigger then some value then you can assume it doesn't move. It is primitive method which needs only to substract both frames (to get zeros for the same pixels) and sum all values to get single value which you can compare with some predefined value. With cv2 which use numpy it could be `sum(grey_frame_previous - grey_frame_current) > some_value`

Comment: there will be an issue with multiple moving enemies I think

Comment: better see my answer below - there is method to get `x,y` when you replace `data.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `print( retro.__file__ )` I found folder with module `retro` and checking all subfolders I found folder with `SuperMarioWorld`

On my Linux it is

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/retro/data/stable/SuperMarioWorld-Snes
```

There is file `data.json` which defines how `retro` has to find `score` and  `lives` in `ROM`

In [OpenAI-Retro-SuperMarioWorld-SNES](https://github.com/szmyty/OpenAI-Retro-SuperMarioWorld-SNES) I found [data.json](https://github.com/szmyty/OpenAI-Retro-SuperMarioWorld-SNES/blob/master/data.json) which has also info for `x`, `y`, etc.

If I replace `data.json` then I can get `info["x"]` in code .

But I'm not sure if this file works with every version of `SuperMario`.

I tested with `Super Mario World (Europe) (Rev 1)` which I found on

https://ia800201.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/7/items/No-Intro-Collection_2016-01-03_Fixed/Nintendo%20-%20Super%20Nintendo%20Entertainment%20System.zip

but there are other versions - Europe, USA, Japan.